# Display 'post_date' of a pod in the F, j, Y format

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering if it is possible to display the post date of a pod page in a similar way to the wordpress format. At the moment the date shows like this: 2014-12-05 14:34 and I'd prefer to have it showing as "Date, Month, Year".

The main issue before was that for each instance of the pod it would grab the date of the main page rather than the date for each pod that was being brought through. I now have the correct date showing, just not in the desired format.

I've included my current code for this page as well:

```
// Define custom query parameters
$params = array(
     'orderby' => 'date DESC',
'limit' => 4,
);
$postPods = pods('post', $params, array());
?>

<!-- Header content brought in before this file -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
        <?php
        echo '<h1 class="header">';
        the_title();
        echo '</h1>';
        echo '<div class="txtbox">';
        the_content();      
        echo '</div>';
        ?>
        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="container">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php 
        while ($postPods->fetch()) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-12 teambox news">    

            <div class="col-md-6 r-img-border">
                <a href="<?php echo $postPods->display(the_permalink); ?>"><img class="team current-dev" src="<?php echo $postPods->display('landing_page_thumbnail'); ?>" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 news_limiter">
                <h1 class="header"><?php echo $postPods->field('title'); ?></h1>
                <p class="bluetxt"><strong>Posted on: </strong><?php echo $postPods->display('post_date');?></p>
                <p><?php echo $postPods->field('summary'); ?></p>
                <p><a class="btns btn mobhidden btn_foot" href="<?php echo $postPods->display(the_permalink); ?>">Read the full story</a></p>   
                <p><a class="btns1 btn deskhidden" href="<?php echo $postPods->display(the_permalink); ?>">Full story</a></p>   
            </div>
        </div>
<?php }  ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated as I'm stumped, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it when you are printing the date:

```
<?php 
     $dat = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:s', $postPods->display('post_date') );
     echo date_format($dat, 'F, j, Y');
  ?>
```

Comment: That done the trick, thanks so much for the help! The stuff I tried before wasn't quite the same way as this but now I've seen this I know where I went wrong. Cheers.